# Reach form hooks complex nested object get and submit change to api

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hooks

I have started to use this library and hit an issue.

Basically i have the following object structure which i receive from an api request.

```
{
  "introduction": "hello",
  "imageUri": "someimage.jpg",
  "sections": [
    {
      "subSections": [
        {
          "sectionMedia": [
            {
              "externalUri": "https://vimeo.com/1212",
              "id": 17127,
              "type": "video",
              "name": null,
              "description": null,
              "displayOrder": null,
            }
          ],
          "id": 172,
          "name": "Section 1",
          "displayOrder": 1,
        },
        {
          "sectionMedia": [
            {
              "externalUri": "https://vimeo.com/1212",
              "id": 178121,
              "type": "video",
              "name": null,
              "description": null,
              "displayOrder": null
            }
          ],
          "id": 178121,
          "name": "Section 2",
          "displayOrder": 2
        },
      ],
      "sectionMedia": [
        {
          "externalUri": "external.jpg",
          "id": 176,
          "type": "download",
          "name": "Bar Modelling - Series 1 Workbook",
          "description": null,
          "displayOrder": null,
          "createdAt": "2020-06-08T05:13:25+00:00",
          "createdByUser": "/users/109",
          "updatedAt": "2020-07-16T23:08:29+00:00",
          "updatedByUser": "/users/109"
        }
      ],
      "id": 17111,
      "name": "Series",
      "description": "some description",
      "displayOrder": 1,
  ]
}
```

So once the user has edited the data and this may not be all fields i need to submit and merge it with the object that we received and post full object back to the server.

However if i edit something within the array i need to show as the array name such as e.g if i updated the externalUri in sectionMedia with id 176 it should have the correct object structure when submitting the structure is flat like so:

`name: "some name" externalUri: "newimage.jpg"`

So wanted to see if there is a nice way to do this without actually searching the object and replacing when doing an onblur as will affect performance

Hope this makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this is what you want but we can loop through the object

```
 const [ fields, setFields ] = useState(
    {
      "externalUri": "external.jpg",
      "id": 176,
      "type": "download",
      "name": "Bar Modelling - Series 1 Workbook",
      "description": null,
      "displayOrder": null,
      "createdAt": "2020-06-08T05:13:25+00:00",
      "createdByUser": "/users/109",
      "updatedAt": "2020-07-16T23:08:29+00:00",
      "updatedByUser": "/users/109"
    })
```

We render the inputs here.

```
return Object.keys(fields).map( item => <input name={item} value={fields[item]} onChange={onChange} />
```

Then for the onchange.. we use the input name and add it back to the object.

```
const onChange = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value
    const name = e.target.name
    setFields( prev => ({ ...fields, [name]: value})) //this retains the original object, but change only the edited field
}
```

THOUGH.. submitting back the entire document back to the server is probably bad practice.

You should probably only submit fields that were changed.

#### WHY?

Because we cannot trust anything submitted from client, if you merge and resubmit the entire document, you need to make sure you re-validate the ENTIRE document.

Comment: Thanks for that. So question on this. If i have an array with multiple objects which is nested further down the tree how would this work? sectionMedia is the example